# Inno Setup - how to repeat an execution of .exe file in [Run] section when it fails

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to repeat an .exe file after an termination. So when you terminate a running executable program (from `Run` section), because an error code appears, and then you want to execute the same program again (something like a loop).

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that it's possible in the `Run` section. Except that you may be able to do a limited number of retries, based on a non-zero exit code using `cmd` `||` operator:

```
[Run]
Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/c command params || command params || ..."
```

---

If you need better control, you should use [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) from [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) in `ssInstall` or `ssPostInstall` step, like:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Code: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    while (not Exec('command', 'params', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code)) or
          (Code <> 0) do ;
  end;
end;
```